# A growth rate principle for entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\widehat{f}(\xi) = O(e^{-a|\xi|^p})$ as $|\xi| \rightarrow \infty$ and $p>1$. Then, show that $f$ is entire and
$$ |f(z)| \leq Be^{a|z|^q}  $$
where $p$ and $q$ are conjugate and
$$\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} dx $$

*Some background:* This is problem 1, Ch.4 in Stein's *complex analysis*. I came across it after some preliminary reading on uncertainty principles and harmonic analysis. *Edit*: I originally labelled this post "An uncertainty type principle for entire functions". Although it doesn't appear to imply anything about the concentration of a function near a point, there is a similar theme in the sense of establishing a relationship between the growth/decay rates of a (entire) function and its Fourier transform.
It should also be mentioned that as $p \rightarrow \infty$, $\widehat{f}$ becomes compactly supported and this result implies $f$ has growth order $q \rightarrow 1^+$, which is one direction of the Paley-Weiner theorem.

*Work thus far*: If we define
$$f_n(z) = \int_{-n}^n \widehat{f}(\xi) e^{2 \pi i z \xi} d \xi$$
then $f_n$ is holomorphic for all $n$ and the rapid decay rate of $\widehat{f}$ immediately gives us that $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $f(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{2 \pi i z \xi} d \xi $, making $f$ entire. Now,
\begin{align*}
|f(z)| & \leq \left|  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(\xi) e^{2 \pi i z \xi} d \xi \right| \\
& \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} A e^{-a|\xi|^p} |e^{2 \pi i z \xi}| d \xi \\
& \leq A \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-a|\xi|^p + 2 \pi |z||\xi|} d \xi \\
\end{align*}
We may select $N$ large such that $\int_{|\xi| > N} e^{-a|\xi|^p + 2 \pi |z||\xi|} d \xi \leq 1  $. Then we have
$$ |f(z)| \leq A \int_{-N}^N e^{-a|\xi|^p + 2\pi |z||\xi|} d \xi + 1 \leq \tilde{A} \int_{-N}^N e^{|z|^q} d \xi = A' N e^{|z|^q}  $$
where we are using Young's inequality $ |z||\xi| \leq |\xi|^p/p + |z|^q/q \leq |\xi|^p + |z|^q  $.
The constant $\tilde{A} = A' \cdot N$ depends on $N$ (which in turn depends on $z$). We should be able to do better and get a global constant independent of $N$.

*Edit:* per the comment from user @Shalop, we can make use of "Young's inequality with $\epsilon$", which appears in the appendix of Evan's PDE book. For $\epsilon > 0$ given, we may replace $|\xi|$ with $|\xi \epsilon|$ and $|z|$ with $|z/\epsilon|$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
|\epsilon \xi| |\frac{z}{\epsilon}| \leq \frac{1}{p} \epsilon^p |\xi|^p + \frac{|z|^q}{\epsilon^q q} \leq \epsilon^p |\xi|^p + C(\epsilon) |z|^q \leq \frac{a}{2} |\xi|^p + C(\epsilon) |z|^q 
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|f(z)| & \leq A \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-a|\xi|^p + 2 \pi |z||\xi|} d \xi \\
& \leq A \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-a|\xi|^p + \frac{a}{2} |\xi|^p + c|z|^q} d \xi \\
& = A e^{c|z|^q} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac{a}{2}|\xi|^p} d \xi \\
& = B e^{c|z|^q} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: If you don't care about getting a sharp constant in the exponent, then you can just do $2 \pi |z||\xi| \leq \frac{ a}{2} |\xi|^p + c|z|^q$ where $c$ is large enough (just use the general form of Young's inequality). Then it won't fully cancel the $-a|\xi|^p$ and you'll still have a $-\frac{a}{2}|\xi|^p$ remaining in the exponent. So then the integral over $\Bbb R$ will be finite and you don't even need to restrict to $[-N,N]$.

Comment: By general form I just meant $ab = (\epsilon a)(\epsilon^{-1} b) \le \epsilon^{p} a^p/p + \epsilon^{-q}b^q/q$.

Comment: Excellent! This does it! That inequality is "Young's inequality with $\epsilon$", which appears in the appendix of Evan's PDE book. I had forgotten about it - thanks! - will edit the original post